# how am i able to use regex in a string that has linebreaks in visual basic

Tags: regex, vb.net, http, line-breaks

basically i'm in a bit of a jam because when i have done a web request the page gives me the code which in turn is made a string (that has multiple lines) and so poses my problem if i leave them all on one line it doesn't work but i have no idea how to make it work please help i am new to visual basic and so try not to be too harsh if it is a rookie mistake and in advance thanks for the help

```
Dim cexreg As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<h1>
                                                        <a href="".*"">.*</a>
                                                        </h1>
                                                        <p>.*</p>
                                                        <div class=""prodPrice"">
                                                        <div style=""padding-top: 6px;"">
                                                        <div class=""priceTxt"">WeSell for £.*</div>
                                                        <div class=""priceTxt"">WeBuy for £.*</div>
                                                        <br><div class=""priceTxt"">WeBuy for voucher £.*</div><br>")
```

Comment: There's and overload that takes an options parameter, one of which is multiline. However that appears to be the text you want to match, not the regular expression you want to use to do it. Also Regex for markup is not generally a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Does the regex target string have linebreaks?
Try the workaround below.

```
Dim foo As String = "abc" & vbCrLf & "def"
foo = Replace(foo, vbCrLf, "")

Dim request As String = "abc" & vbCrLf & "def"
request = Replace(request, vbCrLf, "")
Dim regex As New Regex(request)

'IsMatch returns True.
Debug.Print(regex.IsMatch(foo))
```

Comment: is there a way to just remove all of the line breaks in the string? @Jumpei Tanaka

Comment: `vbCrLf` means a linebreak, so to replace `vbCrLf` blank like above is the same as remove.